# Microservice consuming Kafka events through Zuul

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, netflix-zuul

I am new to Microservices architecture.
I want to create a microservice using Netflix OSS.
I want my architecture to look some thing like the one described here.

http://callistaenterprise.se/blogg/teknik/2017/09/13/building-microservices-part-8-logging-with-ELK/

However I want one of my microservice, (which is behind the Zuul Reverse proxy) to consume events from a Kafka events(which is from some other team).
I am not sure If this is a good idea, since this will expose my microservices, which is supposed to be abstracted from outside world behind my Zuul wall.

Is there any other way. Can I use my Zuul to consume event streams from kafka and push to my microservice. If yes, how do I stream from my Zuul to microservice?

Answer (score 0):

Zuul will redirect your request to A service HTTP XXXX port /api/v1/input. This microservice as a producer will put message to kafka channel. After kafka consumer will get message and store or analyze. Another microservice can read from database and return response after frontend request or do push using Server Sent Events or Vertx message bus....